# Returning view model cannot recognize entity framework

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, viewmodel

Model:

```
Public partial class tbl_pictures {

public int picture_id
public string picture_content
public int user_no (foreign key)

public virtual tbl_user tbl_user {get;set;}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel 
public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users> users;
public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_pictures> images;
```

Home Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, MyViewModel model , tbl_pics pic)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {                 
                file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                                                      + file.FileName);
                byte[] data = new byte[] { };
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }
               pic.picture_content = file.FileName;
               pic.emp_no = 6;
               db.tbl_pictures.Add(pic);
               db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

         return this.View(new MyViewModel
        {
            images = pic //ERROR HERE
        });
    }
```

Razor View:

```
@foreach (var img in Model.images) {
        <img src="~/images/@img.profile_content" width="100" height="100"     />
        }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post,
                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.picture_content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image"
                   type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    }
```

When I returing a view the img states it cannot be implicitbility converted as an explicit coversion exists? , I am aiming to store images within tbl_pictures and returning a view model so the razor view can recognize the content that is stored model.images?

Comment: Is `tbl_pics` the same as `tbl_pictures` ?

Comment: First, at least give us code that compiles. Second, where is the error occurring?

Comment: @Glitch100 Yes it is , apologies ,where the codes state "Error Here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tbl_pics` is the same as `tbl_pictures`, then it looks like the issue you have is that you are trying to pass your single object to your `IEnumerable`
in the view Model.

Instead create a new `Array`, `List<T>` or anything that implements the IEnumerable interface and populate it with the `pic` and assign that to the `images` property.

```
new MyViewModel
{
    images = new Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_pictures[] { pic };
}
```

---

Array used instead of List thanks to @[Matias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401769/matias-cicero)

Comment: For the record, you can also create a fixed array: `images = new Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_pictures[] { pic }`

Comment: Aye - anything implements the interface, personally just like the list, but probably better to do the array as single element. I will update code

Comment: In the razor view model.images states object reference not set to an instance of an object... I don't get it? I clearly returned images in my view.

Comment: Have you made the change I suggest @AqibMehrban

Comment: Yes I did :) @Glitch100

Comment: And in your post, `Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, MyViewModel model , tbl_pics pic)` that last parameter- pic- what type is that?

Comment: I got it working now , my get method wasn't returning any model.pics but thanks for your help , it worked :)!